# jquery ui dialog scrollable, can't select checkboxes at bottom of dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery ui popup with that needs vertical scrollbars due to amount of content.

There is a checkbox at the bottom of the popup and I can't get this to be selectable, the focus just jumps straight to the control at the top of the popup whenever I try to click the checkbox.

example code is as follows

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<a href="javascript:openPersonDialog();">Open the Dialog</a>

<div id="personDialog" class="ui-content" data-position-to="window" style="padding-bottom: 2em; height:400px; max-height:400px; overflow-y:auto; min-width: 600px; max-width: 600px;" data-role="popup" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
    <input type="hidden" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input type="text" id="txtA" />
    <div style="height:700px; background-color:lightblue;">

    </div>
    <input id="chkA" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="chkA">Test Checkbox</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


function openPersonDialog()
{
    $('#personDialog').popup('open');
}

</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas, thanks very much for any help you could give me

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and put this on my local dev box and it works no issue for me I can check it and uncheck it no issue, you can view it [here](http://dev.francispbaker.com/stackoverflow/39823522.html) try for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question @Baker, I probably didn't make it clear that I was using jQuery mobile, so have added that to my question